# Get what date it is based on week number and day number asp classic?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I need to know what date it is based on a week number and a day number.

So if I have weeknr=3 and day=1(for today- sunday) and lets say the year=2016 how can I make this into 2016-01-24.

Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best help will be the `DatePart` function (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_datepart.asp) for docs). It's not altogether straightforward, because there are options to consider like "first day of week" and "first week of year", but you can define those in `DatePart`.

This would be my solution:

```vbs
option explicit

function getDateByWeek(year, week, day)
    dim dt, woy, add_days

    dt = DateSerial(year, 1, 1)
    do
        woy = DatePart("ww", dt, vbSunday, vbFirstFullWeek)
        ' possibly change options [,firstdayofweek[,firstweekofyear]]
        dt = DateAdd("d", 1, dt)
    loop while woy<>1

    add_days = week * 7 + day - 2
    ' -1 because we already added one day extra in the loop
    ' -1 to correct given day (sunday = 1)

    getDateByWeek = DateAdd("d", add_days, dt)
end function

Response.Write "RESULT: " & getDateByWeek(2016, 3, 1) '  -> 24.01.2016
```

I start by finding the first day of the first week in a loop and then adding the cumulative amount of days to have a result.

Comment: Try putting <!-- language: lang-vbs --> just before your code block, gpinkas.

Comment: @Paul Or add [tag:vbscript] to the list of tags on the question to have it automatically applied.

Comment: @Lankymart: I did not know that, either!  ;o)  Nice tip.

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way is to work out what the week start of the year is and take it from there.

Firstly, the first Thursday of any year is always in the first week of the year, so a simple calculation of adding the correct number onto the 1st January is obvious. After this we simply mulitply out the weeks and add the days:

```vbs
Const C_THURSDAY = 5
Function GetDateFromYWD(y, w, d)
    Dim tDate, aDate
    'Get the first of the year...
    tDate = DateSerial(y, 1, 1)
    'Workout the start of the first week in the year...
    aDate = tDate + Int(WeekDay(tDate)>C_THURSDAY And 7) - WeekDay(tDate)
    'Add on the number of weeks plus days we're looking for...
    aDate = aDate + (w * 7) + d
    GetDateFromYWD = aDate
End Function
```

Comment: Just thought I'd re-instate this with a slight modification. Unlike gpinkas' version, mine uses maths and a Boolean comparison to achieve the same thing.